# I want to count my every right and wrong answer submitted in my quiz app and want to display score in textview

Tags: java, android, textview

This is the method I have created to check the condition
For the right answer, I am showing the png image and the same for the wrong answer

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressed) {

    boolean answerProvided = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isQuestionTrueAnswer();

    int messageStringId = 0;


    if (answerProvided == userPressed) {

        messageStringId = R.string.correct_toast;

        mGreenTick.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_tick);

        mGreenTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        
    }

    else {

        messageStringId = R.string.incorrect_toast;

        mGreenTick.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_cross);

        mGreenTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

  //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, messageStringId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I have called the method checkAnswer() method in the true button click and false button click below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);

    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Does nothing yet, but soon!

           checkAnswer(true);

           mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);

           mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);

           mMoreInfoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




        }

    });

    mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);

    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Does nothing yet, but soon!

          checkAnswer(false);

            mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);

            mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);

            mMoreInfoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    });
```

Now, i have used intent method in Score Button click and in the ScoreActivity.class i want to show the

store in textview.

please tell me how to count the true answer and wrong answer and store the score in the variable which i

can show in textview

Please help me.

```
mScoreButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.score_button);

    mScoreButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mScoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

            finish();

        }

    });
```

Comment: Please edit the code for me i have declare two variables, initialized with zero, in the end i have declared third variable float TotalScore = plusMarks - minusMarks       Now how to access this variable outside the method. please edit the code

Answer (score 0):

```
private int trueCount = 0;
private int falseCount = 0;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressed) {

    boolean answerProvided = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isQuestionTrueAnswer();

    int messageStringId = 0;


    if (answerProvided == userPressed) {
trueCount++;

        messageStringId = R.string.correct_toast;

        mGreenTick.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_tick);

        mGreenTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        
    }

    else {
falseCount++;

        messageStringId = R.string.incorrect_toast;

        mGreenTick.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_cross);

        mGreenTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

  //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, messageStringId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

...

```
//Displaying int textView
textView.setText(String.format("Right count: %d False count: %d", rightCount, falseCount));
```

Comment: how to transfer the value of rightCount into another Activity textview it is related to intent but I do not know how to pass the value of rightCount in another activity I have created with the help of intent, I want to pass in new activity textview. please help me with this

Comment: intent.putExtra("TRUE_COUNT",trueCount); And than in the second activity you can get this value with getIntent().getStringExtra("TRUE_COUNT");

Comment: where to give this command, explain it briefly please  my main java file is MainActivity.java and the another class i have created ScoreActivity.java, now in this ScoreActivity i have created textview and in this textview i want to pass the value of trueCount. Please explain briefly

Comment: IT IS SHOWING NULL. PLEASE EDIT THE CODE

Answer (score 0):

mFinalMarks = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.final_marks);
mFinalMarks.setText("Final Score is: " + getIntent().getStringExtra("PLUS_MARKS") + "Marks out of 10 ");

```
    getIntent().getStringExtra("PLUS_MARKS");
```

// it is showing null instead of score